# Can you filter/inspect POST method/requests with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, query-string

Can you filter/inspect POST method/requests with htaccess
For example, if you want to filter a `$_GET` variable with htaccess to redirect if a pattern is matched, it would look like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} <script> [NC]
RewriteRule .*$ /mylogPage.php? [L,R=301]
```

Can you do a similar filter for $_POST variables?

I have tried many variations including an attempt to modify `mod_security` through htaccess. I assume in htaccess it will have something to do with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST.
```

I have tried

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} <script> [NC]
RewriteRule .*$ /mylogPage.php? [L,R=301]
```

But it only redirected the page

If this should be done through mod_security, can one edit mod security through htaccess? What would the syntax look like? I have tried but was not successful.

Comment: No, you can not access the request body content using the rewrite engine.

Comment: @CBroe any other way to access it?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/68395 also says you're likely going to have to use mod_security. But you weren't specific on what you have tried so far, or even what _exactly_ you need to achieve.

Comment: I do not see an immediate option for this ... The issue is that "$_POST variables" is a concept that does not exist on the level of the http server (protocol level). So it cannot be handled. You indeed would have to use an additional helper script for this. But then you can simply rewrite _all_ requests to a router script (something like `index.php`) and do the filtering / routing in there.

Comment: If you need to filter out `<script>` like this, then you have bigger problems... HTML should be sanitized (whitelist with safe tags/attributes) or completely escaped (if no HTML formatting is allowed) when displaying your content. Ideally your framework does that automatically unless explicitly disabled in specific cases...

Comment: @ThiefMaster. Thanks I am aware. The plan goes much deeper than simply filtering out `<script>`. I have simply used that as an example. But I do see your point and FULLY agree with you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done research and spoke to my hosting company as well.
If you are on shared hosting, all domains on the same server share the same settings for `mod_security`,so it is not possible to access and/or edit `mod_security` through htaccess. If that was possible, you would modify `mod_security` to affect all website on the server. On shared hosting it is only possible to inspect `$_GET` variables through htaccess.

Answer (score -1):

In case you are on shared facilitating, all spaces on a similar worker share similar settings for `mod_security`, so it is absurd to expect to get to or potentially alter `mod_security` through `htaccess`. In case that was conceivable, you would change `mod_security` to influence all site on the worker. On shared facilitating it is simply conceivable to review `$_GET` factors through `htaccess`.